# NinevehGL, hide status bar

Tags: ios

I am developing a 3D program with the NinevehGl engine.

I tried to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO]` to hide the status bar, but then it left a white space in the original status bar position.

How can I make it render on the full screen?

THX.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `NGLView` frame after you hide the status bar? My guess is it is not resizing to the bounds change. Maybe it is as simple as just clamping your view to its superview to have it resize.

`NGLView` should autoresize like a normal `UIView` which it is a subclass of, however you will probably have to reconfigure the camera aspect ratio after the resize. This can be done automatically by setting `[yourCamera autoAdjustAspectRatio:YES animated:YES]`